# How do I save a video which I've panned with mpv?

Tags: video-editor

I have *mpv 0.27.2 (C) 2000-2017 mpv/MPlayer/mplayer2 projects* running on Kubuntu 18.04.

I can view a selected area of a video, *out.mp4*, by using

```
mpv --speed=0.8 --video-pan-x=-0.1 --video-pan-y=0.07 out.mp4
```

How can I saved the "panned" video? Simply appending `> out1.mp4` or even `>> out1.mp4` creates a very tiny file, 135 B, with the name *out1.mp4* but with no actual content whereas the size of `out.mp4` is 46.3 MiB.

I guess I can use simplescreenrecorder if there isn't a direct route.

Comment: Couldn't you use `ffmpeg` for video conversion?

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. It's a case of arson in my housing society! Someone set fire to three bikes.